# Mongoose query problem - $push pushing element twice

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to push single string into array from document in my mongodb collection.
I'm using nodejs with mongoose v5.3.1

I'm putting data into my html form and then, submitting it to server.

There is my HTML:

```
<form action="/addchat" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="chatid" id="addchatid">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="chatname">
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="chatbot" id="chatbot">
            <option value="684206793:AAH5uDpus4Ngw1Z60pj6iOedBGCM8Vq0">botname1</option></select><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

There is my app code:

```
app.post('/addchat', async (req, res) => {

    var czat = {
      name: req.body.chatname,
      chatid: req.body.chatid
    }

    await botsmodel.updateOne({
        token: req.body.chatbot
      }, {
        $push: {
          chats: czat
        }
      },
      async (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`Error updating chats ${err}`)
        } else {
          console.log(`Chats updated for ${req.body.chatbot}`);
        }

      });


    await res.redirect('/')


});
```

There is my collection schema:

```
var schemaOptions = {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  }
};

var botyschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  token: String,
  chats: Array
}, schemaOptions);
```

After executing, my console looks like it have pushed "czat" object once:

```
Chats updated for 684206793:AAH5uDpus4Ngw1Z60pj6iOedBGCM8Vq0
```

But in my collection two objects have appended into my array, it looks that:

```
 "chats": [
            {
                "name": "chat_main",
                "chatid": "100516120633"
            },
            {
                "name": "chat_main",
                "chatid": "100516120633"
            }
          ],
```

I'm missing something in my schema or query?

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem, and I solved it by changing `$push` to `$addToSet`.

[$addToSet documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet)

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, i got stuck for an entire day thinking its anything else but this.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if addToSet is the best solution because the query being executed twice.

**If you used a callback and a promise simultaneously, it would make the query executes twice.**

So choosing one of them would make it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Try changing your schema to this

```
var schemaOptions = {
timestamps: true,
   toJSON: {
   virtuals: true
},
toObject: {
  virtuals: true
  }
};

var botyschema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: String,
name: String,
token: String,

chats: [{ 
  "name": String,
  "chatid": Number
 }]

}, schemaOptions);
```

Or you could try just

```
chats: [{}]
```

But I guess that opens it up to recieve any input.

Comment: I just recalled that i had a similair question a while back, check out 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857894/mongodb-mongoose-on-save-push-comment-into-array-in-the-array-youll-see-com/52414669#52414669

It´s about pushing an object into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem same you, so I tried remove "await", and I successfully